# Created a stack and the push() method is not working

Tags: java, compiler-errors, char, stack, push

My push method for my stack is not working and I do not understand why.
Eclipse says the argument is not applicable for the primitive type for my Stack.

```
  Stack<Bracket> openingBrackets = new Stack<>();

  for (int position = 1; position <= text.length(); ++position) {

     char next = text.charAt(position - 1);

     if ( next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {

         openingBrackets.push(next);

     }

     System.out.print(openingBrackets.pop());

  }
```

I'm expecting the (, [, { to get added to the stack

Comment: What is a `Bracket` and why would it be compatible with `char`?

Comment: Right, the stack takes types of `Bracket` and you tried to push a `char`.  Maybe you meant `push( new Bracket( next ) )`?

Comment: FYI, it's customary to loop from 0 while `position < text.length()` so you don't have to adjust by -1.

Comment: When you say 'is not working', what you mean is 'does not compile'. It isn't the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize or declare a [Stack in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-class-in-java/) you must specify the type within the carrots `<>`.

Java collections are generic and these brackets are used to define the type of the data stored inside. e.g. `Stack<Integer>`. In this case you're pushing characters so you have two options:

1. Specify type: `Stack<Character> openingBrackets = new Stack<Character>();` (Recommended)
2. Type agnostic: `Stack<Object> openingBrackets = new Stack<Object>();`

Side note: only `pop()` if there are items in the stack. So be sure to check for that :)

Comment: That's not "default initialization". It's a raw type, and it's Very Bad. If you want a Stack that's type agnostic, use `Stack<Object>`, not a raw `Stack`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not very good at communicating in English, but you can try running the following code to see if it meets your needs

```java
package org.example;

import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "([{[[sad";
        Stack<Character> openingBrackets = new Stack<>();

        for (int position = 0; position < text.length(); position++) {
            char next = text.charAt(position);

            if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
                openingBrackets.push(next);
            }

        }

        openingBrackets.forEach(System.out::println);
    }


}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).